# Convert Json to XML - Json with array values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, converters

I know there's a lot of similar questions like mine, but none of them worked for me.
My json file has array for actors, directors and genre. I'm having difficult to deal if this arrays while building the xml.

This is the json file:

```
[
   {
      "title":"The Kissing Booth",
      "year":"2018",
      "actors":[
         "Megan du Plessis",
         "Lincoln Pearson",
         "Caitlyn de Abrue",
         "Jack Fokkens",
         "Stephen Jennings",
         "Chloe Williams",
         "Michael Miccoli",
         "Juliet Blacher",
         "Jesse Rowan-Goldberg",
         "Chase Dallas",
         "Joey King",
         "Joel Courtney",
         "Jacob Elordi",
         "Carson White",
         "Hilton Pelser"
      ],
      "genre":[
         "Comedy",
         "Romance"
      ],
      "description":"A high school student is forced to confront her secret crush at a kissing booth.",
      "directors":[
         "Vince Marcello"
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Dune",
      "year":"2020",
      "actors":[
         "Rebecca Ferguson",
         "Zendaya",
         "Jason Momoa",
         "Timoth\u00e9e Chalamet",
         "Dave Bautista",
         "Josh Brolin",
         "Oscar Isaac",
         "Stellan Skarsg\u00e5rd",
         "Javier Bardem",
         "Charlotte Rampling",
         "David Dastmalchian",
         "Stephen McKinley Henderson",
         "Sharon Duncan-Brewster",
         "Chen Chang",
         "Babs Olusanmokun"
      ],
      "genre":[
         "Adventure",
         "Drama",
         "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "description":"Feature adaptation of Frank Herbert's science fiction novel, about the son of a noble family entrusted with the protection of the most valuable asset and most vital element in the galaxy.",
      "directors":[
         "Denis Villeneuve"
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Parasite",
      "year":"2019",
      "actors":[
         "Kang-ho Song",
         "Sun-kyun Lee",
         "Yeo-jeong Jo",
         "Woo-sik Choi",
         "So-dam Park",
         "Jeong-eun Lee",
         "Hye-jin Jang",
         "Myeong-hoon Park",
         "Ji-so Jung",
         "Hyun-jun Jung",
         "Keun-rok Park",
         "Jeong Esuz",
         "Jo Jae-Myeong",
         "Ik-han Jung",
         "Kim Gyu Baek"
      ],
      "genre":[
         "Comedy",
         "Drama",
         "Thriller"
      ],
      "description":"Greed and class discrimination threaten the newly formed symbiotic relationship between the wealthy Park family and the destitute Kim clan.",
      "directors":[
         "Bong Joon Ho"
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Money Heist",
      "year":null,
      "actors":[
         "\u00darsula Corber\u00f3",
         "\u00c1lvaro Morte",
         "Itziar Itu\u00f1o",
         "Pedro Alonso",
         "Miguel Herr\u00e1n",
         "Jaime Lorente",
         "Esther Acebo",
         "Enrique Arce",
         "Darko Peric",
         "Alba Flores",
         "Fernando Soto",
         "Mario de la Rosa",
         "Juan Fern\u00e1ndez",
         "Rocco Narva",
         "Paco Tous",
         "Kiti M\u00e1nver",
         "Hovik Keuchkerian",
         "Rodrigo De la Serna",
         "Najwa Nimri",
         "Luka Peros",
         "Roberto Garcia",
         "Mar\u00eda Pedraza",
         "Fernando Cayo",
         "Antonio Cuellar Rodriguez",
         "Anna Gras",
         "Aitana Rinab Perez",
         "Olalla Hern\u00e1ndez",
         "Carlos Su\u00e1rez",
         "Mari Carmen S\u00e1nchez",
         "Antonio Romero",
         "Pep Munn\u00e9"
      ],
      "genre":[
         "Action",
         "Crime",
         "Mystery",
         "Thriller"
      ],
      "description":"An unusual group of robbers attempt to carry out the most perfect robbery in Spanish history - stealing 2.4 billion euros from the Royal Mint of Spain."
   },
   {
      "title":"The Vampire Diaries",
      "year":null,
      "actors":[
         "Paul Wesley",
         "Ian Somerhalder",
         "Kat Graham",
         "Candice King",
         "Zach Roerig",
         "Michael Trevino",
         "Nina Dobrev",
         "Steven R. McQueen",
         "Matthew Davis",
         "Michael Malarkey"
      ],
      "genre":[
         "Drama",
         "Fantasy",
         "Horror",
         "Mystery",
         "Romance",
         "Thriller"
      ],
      "description":"The lives, loves, dangers and disasters in the town, Mystic Falls, Virginia. Creatures of unspeakable horror lurk beneath this town as a teenage girl is suddenly torn between two vampire brothers."
   }
]
```

I want to convert my json file to xml, and I my python code:

```
import json as j
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("imdb_movie_sample.json") as json_format_file:
    data = j.load(json_format_file)

root = ET.Element("movie")

ET.SubElement(root,"title").text = data["title"]
ET.SubElement(root,"year").text = str(data["year"])

actors = ET.SubElement(root,"actors") #.text = data["actors"]
actors.text = ''
for i in jsondata[0]['movie'][0]['actors']:
    actors.text = actors.text + '\n\t\t' + i

genre = ET.SubElement(root,"genre") #.text = data["genre"]
genre.text = ''
for i in jsondata[0]['movie'][0]['genre']:
    genre.text = genre.text + '\n\t\t' + i

ET.SubElement(root,"description").text = data["description"] 

directors = ET.SubElement(root,"directors") #.text = data["directors"]
directors.text = ''
for i in jsondata[0]['movie'][0]['directors']:
    directors.text = directors.text + '\n\t\t' + i

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("imdb_sample.xml")
```

Does anyone know how to help me doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you coding this yourself? There are tools available to convert json to xml.

Comment: @Mike67 appreciate your help, can you please tell me one?

Comment: I just used this site and the xml looks correct: https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-xml.htm

Comment: @Mike67 Thank you ! It seems it worked here too.

Comment: It's actually quite unusual to find that on off-the-shelf json-to-xml converter produces exactly the XML you want. Usually you have to do some post-processing, and in many cases that means you might as well do the whole job yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on pypi. I would always try looking on pypi to see what exists before asking others. Its an awesome resource with python packages created by tons of developers.

https://pypi.org/project/json2xml/